# SQL - Update to table, no index

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have two tables: `DIM_Staff` and `FACT_Sales`

I want to update `[e-mail]` to `FACT_Sales` from `DIM_Staff`.

The only way to link the `[e-mail]` is through `DIM_Staff.[Name]` and `FACT_Sales.[Name]` since there is no social security number.

I have already gone through both tables to check for misspelling.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
UPDATE [vdb].[dbo].[FACT_Sales] 
SET [e-mail] = (SELECT [e-mail] FROM DIM_Staff WHERE [Name] = [dbo].[FACT_Sales].[Name])


UPDATE [vdb].[dbo].[FACT_Sales] 
SET [e-mail] = (SELECT [e-mail] FROM DIM_Staff WHERE [Name] in (SELECT [Name] FROM [dbo].[FACT_Sales])
```

Error message:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , > >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

It should be a pretty basic update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the follwoing

```
UPDATE t
SET t.[e-mail] = t2.[e-mail]
from [vdb].[dbo].[FACT_Sales] t
inner join DIM_Staff t2
on t.Name = t2.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

It is, but you have people in DIM_Staff sharing the same name. You need to resolve that first.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can't do that query because it would be akin to doing

`set email = val1, val2, val3`

which is not valid

I'm not sure what dbms that is, but in PostgreSQL and MySQL you should be able to do an update over an inner join, that way, all rows that don't match the condition are excluded and you can do the update simply that way.

Start it off with a select query to get the values you want then change it into an update statement.